# Query using variable from url not executing - Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, jquery, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have jquery send out a request to the api endpoint. Code below:

```
$.get("http://localhost:5000/api/update/"+ elm2, function(data){});
```

The endpoint is defined like this:

```
@app.route('/api/update/<id>', methods=['GET'])
def check_new_entries(id):
    result = Trades.query.filter_by(id=id).first_or_404()
    new_entries = Trades.query.filter(Trades.time_recorded > result.time_recorded).all()
```

The table being queried from is:

```
class Trades(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.String,default=lambda: str(uuid4().hex), primary_key=True)
    amount = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=False)
    time_recorded = db.Column(db.DateTime, unique=False)
```

The problem:
Jquery is successfully sending the correct request, with the variable being of type string but when the first query is executed, it fails to return anything. 
I have a similar endpoint in another application and it works fine.. why is this one an exception? What could be missing? I am sure that the record that I am querying is in the database so it should return it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@app.route('/api/update/<id>', methods=['GET',])
def check_new_entries(id):
    result = Trades.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
    if result:
        new_entries = Trades.query.filter(Trades.time_recorded >= result.time_recorded).all()
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to show the table... the primary key is a string - of type uuid4().hex

Comment: The check for if result is well handled by the first_or_404 method. The problem is that the entry is in the database yet for some reason it cannot be fetched. I am so confused by why the query just wont work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that some unexpected space was before the rest of the string. The error originated from jquery and jinja where jquery was getting the html contents of an element and sending them as the variable. The jinja syntax was something like:
`<p> {{ variable }}</p>`
When jquery fetches the html contents, it takes the space btwn the paragraph opening tag and the opening curly braces as well. The variable transmitted had a leading space which caused the error.